# Unique values from random()

Tags: java, arrays, random, processing

I have an array where I am loading 10 images in it, as one can see below:

```
int maxImages = 10; // Total # of images
int imageIndex = int(random(10)); // Initial image to be displayed is the first

// Declaring an array of images.
PImage[] images = new PImage[maxImages];

// Loading the images into the array
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i ++ ) {
    images[i] = loadImage( "assets/images/image" + i + ".jpg" ); 
  }
```

When certain conditions are met I am then using `random()` to generate a new value and save it in a new variable called `imageIndex`. As you can see below:

```
imageIndex = int(random(images.length));
```

After this is generated I am then calling the image with the new random number in the following way:

```
gameimages = loadImage( "assets/images/image" + imageIndex + ".jpg" );
```

The above implementation is working perfectly however random numbers are sometimes being generated more than once, I want them uniquely randomised from 1-10. Can anyone suggest me the best way to go about implementing this ?

Comment: @fge I am using processing which is an open source programming language and integrated development environment (IDE) built for the electronic arts. It uses a base of plain java

Comment: use a List rather than an array, and use collection.shuffle once your list is filled

Comment: why would something based on java use syntax such as `int(...)`? this is weird

Comment: @njzk2 could you kindly provide me an example to my question with your solution. Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2):

Use the collection shuffle:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();    
for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {       
    numbers.add(i+1);     
}      
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

Comment: `List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(images.length)`

Comment: @Toma but how will that generate unique random numbers from random in the variable `imageIndex` ?

Comment: You can use a variable "counter" which will iterate through ArrayList numbers and return numbers.get(counter). Once you get one random number you will increment counter.

Comment: @Toma can you provide me an example on how to implement your solution please

Comment: First declare a variable "counter" and ArrayList "numbers" on the top of the class.
In constructor of the class, or in other possible place, shuffle ArrayList:
`   numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();   
   for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {       
     numbers.add(i+1);     
   }      
   Collections.shuffle(numbers);`

Use ArrayList in your code:
imageIndex = numbers.get(counter++);

Comment: Check accepted answer here , there is an array randomizer http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/3546/how-to-randomize-order-of-array/p1 shuffleArray method

Comment: @Toma thanks for your explanation, however i'm quite a newbie in this, could you maybe edit your answer with a working solution that I then be able to integrate in my code ?